# AsyncTask issues

Tags: android

I've got following code in my AsyncTask. The only thing I want the AsyncTask to do, is to sleep for 1000 ms, while showing a ProgressDialog.

```
package something.something.Logic;

import android.R;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DeviceScan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog dialog;
Context _context; 

public DeviceScan(Context context) {    
    _context = context; 
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);  
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

      dialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
      dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
      dialog.setMessage("Searching for devices..");
      dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      dialog.setCancelable(false);
      dialog.show();    
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

      for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      return "";
}

 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

     /*
      * When the background thread is finished, do something here
      */
     Toast.makeText(_context, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     dialog.dismiss(); 
 }
}
```

Then I call the AsyncTask this way:

```
import something.something.Logic.*;

public void onClick(View view){

    switch(view.getId())    {

        case R.id.button1:
            new DeviceScan(getApplicationContext()).execute("");
      break;

    }
}
```

But my app just crashes when I hit the button, I cant find any information from the debugger. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If crashes then logcat output please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the `ProgressDialog` twice. Remove the creation from the `onPreExecute`.
Another thing is, pass the `this` reference of the the `Activity` as the `context` in the constructor of `DeviceScan`

```
import something.something.Logic.*;

public void onClick(View view){

    switch(view.getId())    {

        case R.id.button1:
            new DeviceScan(MyActivity.this).execute("");
      break;

    }
}
```

Also, change the signature of `onPostExecute` as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way....Put the async like this way....if you don't get it then let me know..Regards

```
package something.something.Logic;

import android.R;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

ProgressDialog dialog;


public void onClick(View view){


    switch(view.getId())    {

        case R.id.button1:
            new DeviceScan().execute("");
      break;

    }
}
public class DeviceScan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

protected void onPreExecute() {

      dailog=ProgressDialog.show(classname.this,"Please Wair..","Searching for devices..",false);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    return "";
}

 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

     /*
      * When the background thread is finished, do something here
      */
     dialog.dismiss();
     Toast.makeText(_context, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `onPostExecute(Integer result)` to `onPostExecute(String result)`.

Comment: It is still wrong to have an Integer as the result Parameter if it is String in the Class definition. As it is in your example.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to pass in the context. it's supposed to be a field of the `Activity` class and what you do is create dialog from the `doInBackground` function.

Comment: But how should I create the Toast in the onPostExecute method, when the makeToast needs a context as the first parameter?

Comment: you can use the parent class as the context and show it whenever you want to

Answer (score 0):

Just Change it .

```
 Toast.makeText(_context, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
 dialog.dismiss();
```

TO

```
  dialog.dismiss(); 
  Toast.makeText(_context, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You show message before dismiss() dialog.

I think that make problem.

Thanks